# Any suggestions to optimize the following delphi code?

Tags: delphi

I wrote the following code to demonstrate string manipulation to a friend. The function works as required. My question is, can the code be optimized (shortened)?

## Usage:

```
txtPassword.Text := toPassword(txtPassword.Text);
```

## Function:

1. Get the input, change it to Uppercase - apple -> APPLE
2. Each letter gets replaced with the preceding letter except A and Z -     B becomes A
3. Add the word's length at the end
4. Reverse the original Uppercased word and Append it to the end

   ```
   function TForm1.toPassword(input: string): string;
   var
     strMyABC, strWord, strAppend, strResult : string;
     I, intAns : Integer;
   begin
     strMyABC := 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
     strWord := Uppercase(input);

     for I := 1 to strWord.Length do
     begin
       intAns := Pos(strWord[I], strMyABC);
       if (intAns = 1) or (intAns = 26) then
       begin
         strAppend := strWord[I];
       end
       else
       begin
         strAppend := strMyABC[intAns-1];
       end;
       strResult := strResult + strAppend;
     end;

     result := strResult + IntToStr(strWord.Length) + ReverseString(strWord);

   end;
   ```

Comment: Do you want less code or faster code?

Comment: Shorter code as speed is not a requirement

Comment: Best place to start optimisation is to avoid unnecessary local variables which can mask edge cases, imo.  The only local variable you actually need is the Result proxy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question belongs on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can get rid of the alphabet string, since it's only used to determine whether your char is an A or a Z. Function below works the same for letters, but has a slightly different effect on other characters. Where I subtract one from the character itself, you basically read 2 bytes of the 4 bytes string length indicator and use that as the char value. I think both are equally illegal. ;)

```
function TForm1.toPassword(input: string): string;
var
  c: Char;
  strWord: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  strWord := Uppercase(input);
  for c in strWord do
    Result := Result + IfThen(CharInSet(c, ['A', 'Z']), c, Char(Ord(c)-1));
  Result := Result + strWord.Length.ToString + ReverseString(strWord);
end;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!